Is it possible to open the VS Code merge UI programmatically without using git from within my own extension?
I am trying to build an extension that can do a custom 2-way and 3-way without using git.
Essentially, I want to call it in my own extension like so:
      await vscode.commands.executeCommand("vscode.openMergeEditor", {
        base: { uri: baseUri },
        input1: { uri: input1Uri, title: "Modified Version" },
        input2: { uri: input2Uri, title: "Other Version" },
        result: { uri: resultUri, title: "Merged Result" }
      });

I know that VS Code has a merge interface but I just cannot find the command required to actually show it. There's only a diff view in the built-in commands: https://code.visualstudio.com/api/references/commands

https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/blob/636a30ec3586b19db0849d581aa38e6ebc04477e/extensions/git/src/commands.ts#L754 ?

@LexLi Thank you. I assume it requires a file schema to work? I will have to save my my files into /tmp before attempting this.

There's the command _open.mergeEditor. Example invocation can be found in the builtin Git extension here. At the time of this writing, its argument type is as follows:

type IRelaxedInputData = { uri: UriComponents; title?: string; detail?: string; description?: string };

type IRelaxedOpenArgs = {
  base: UriComponents | string;
  input1: IRelaxedInputData | string;
  input2: IRelaxedInputData | string;
  output: UriComponents | string;
};


Following validation of input (where input1 and input2 are converted to input data), the command converts the validation result into a IResourceMergeEditorInput and passes it to a call to openEditor on the editor service. The UriComponents type is almost the same as that of the Uri type.
That ending call to openEditor is (I think) analogous to the call to openEditors for commandline --diff. The editor service implementation is mostly here.
Maybe relevant given the URI involvement here (I'm not sure): Open a new file in VS Code via URL with provided text content.

Thank you very much! I will give this a try. The thing is that the files I want to merge are not part of a git repository. In addition to that, they use different URI schema/type.
